# Why is Singleton bad for unit tests?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm currently delving into the discussion about Singleton yes or no, and it seems that one of the main criticism about singleton is that it's hard to unit test applications that use singleton, and I'm trying to figure out why.

I want to refer to  this thread:
[Why is a singleton class hard to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273210/why-is-a-singleton-class-hard-to-test)

In short, the accepted answer there explains that when you have a class `OtherClass` that uses a singleton class `MySingleton`, and say that the Singleton class's methods does something like write to a file, connect to a database, etc. you don't want to do these things in unit tests, you want to mock out that object.

So instead of singleton, you can use Dependency Injection. We want to have a `MyNonSingleton` class that implements some interface, to instantiate and object of it, and pass it in the ctor of `OtherClass`. This way, in unit tests, we can mock the `MyNonSingleton` with a mock class that implements the interface.

Now my question: Assuming that when unit testing, we have a separate application in which we use the tested-out class, I don't understand what is the difference between the 2 approaches? With `MySingleton` - you can provide a mock implementation of `MySingleton` exactly as you would provide a mock implementation that implements the same  interface that `MyNonSingleton` implements, so why is singleton bad for unit tests?

Comment: A singleton is bad for unit tests when it is a *hidden dependency* — accessed directly by the internals of the routine, rather than passed into the routine (dependency injection).

Comment: In addition to ^, Because its stateful. You want your unit tests to not carry state.

Comment: It may be informative to try to actually write tests for a class using a singleton and find out what challenges you face. Depending on your framework, is substituting your mocked singleton as easy as passing in a mock of a non-singleton? Does your framework compile all your tests into big exe or individual ones per test? And so what consequences does that make for needing different variations of the singleton for different tests? Or for simple test performance? Etc.